# 2003 Mitsubishi Galant 2003

Tags: mitsubishi, smoke

I have a 2003 Mitsubishi Galant es, I started my car and while driving the car shut off and started to smoke grey out of the engine bay on the drivers side, 1/4th of the engine. The car will not turn on but will turnover

Comment: Post a picture of your engine bay?

Comment: Any warnings, like temperature gauge maxing out, or warning lights come on?

Comment: All Fluids present and correct? Any staining or puddling present? Is there any oil slick/sheen/foam in the coolant over-flow bottle? Do you have the ability to perform a compression test?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell what's going on from just "smoke coming from the engine." Try to find where the smoke came from. Look for:

1. splashing pattern indicating something leaked
2. cut, scrubbed or chafed hoses
3. seized belts (have somebody turn the engine over while you are looking at the belts, see if they move. Watch your fingers!)
4. dried out, rotted or leaking gaskets